# Converting a Sheets API 'batchGet' request into a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-sheets-api

In order to reduce the number of API calls to the Sheets API and aviod the dreaded 'error 429' message, I wish to utilise the Sheets API 'batchGet' function.  I have placed all of my relevant information into one google spreadsheet `spreadsheet_id`, containing multiple worksheets `ranges`.  The next step is to convert this batchGet request into a Pandas Dataframe.

Here is my code...  If anyone can provide guidance on next steps to get this into a pandas df that would be great.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import pandas as pd


SCOPES = [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('creds.json', SCOPES)

service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

# The ID of the spreadsheet to retrieve data from.
spreadsheet_id = 'my_spreadheet_id'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

# The A1 notation of the values to retrieve.
ranges = ['2016_IGA!A2:BD',  '2017_IGA!A2:BD',  '2018_IGA!A2:BD',  '2019_IGA!A2:BD',  '2020_IGA!A2:BD',
'2016_Coles!A2:BD',  '2017_Coles!A2:BD',  '2018_Coles!A2:BD',  '2019_Coles!A2:BD',  '2020_Coles!A2:BD',                          # TODO: Update placeholder value.
'2016_WW!A2:BD',  '2017_WW!A2:BD',  '2018_WW!A2:BD',  '2019_WW!A2:BD',  '2020_WW!A2:BD', 
'2018_Aldi!A2:BD',  '2019_Aldi!A2:BD',  '2020_Aldi!A2:BD']

value_render_option = 'FORMATTED_VALUE'  

request = service.spreadsheets().values().batchGet(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, ranges=ranges, valueRenderOption=value_render_option)
response = request.execute()
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet and sample output you want? Of course, please remove your personal information from them.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the `values` from the response, and then create a `DataFrame` from the resulting list.

```py
sheet_values = response.get('values', [])

# Optional: Perform any data cleaning/wrangling operations (Date/currency conversion)

# Create a dataframe with the extracted values
df_sheet = DataFrame(sheet_values, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

Comment: thanks Juan but when I do this, my df_sheet returns empty.    In my spreadsheet, the 'values' are values derrived from formulas - would this have an impact?

Comment: I believe I also ran into this issue when I had to implement GA on my side. Because I have to do data cleaning, I ended up appending values into a different list, which parsed completely fine. I used the code provided by the official [Google API Docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) - Let me know if this helps!

Comment: ok, I have solved the problem. I needed to actually have `sheet_values = response.get('valueRanges', [])`   and then normalise this json reponse using the following.  .  `df = json_normalize(sheet_values, sep = ",",record_path='values')`  Works perfectly

Comment: Ah, interesting! I'll be sure to write this down should I find this problem in the future. Glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 1):

building on @juan Morais comments with a few adaptions of my own,  here is the final solution..

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize


SCOPES = [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('creds.json', SCOPES)

service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

# The ID of the spreadsheet to retrieve data from.
spreadsheet_id = 'my_spreadheet_id' 

# The A1 notation of the values to retrieve.
ranges = ['2016_IGA!A2:Be',  '2017_IGA!A2:Be',  '2018_IGA!A2:Be',  '2019_IGA!A2:Be',  '2020_IGA!A2:Be',
'2016_Coles!A2:Be',  '2017_Coles!A2:Be',  '2018_Coles!A2:Be',  '2019_Coles!A2:Be',  '2020_Coles!A2:Be',                          # TODO: Update placeholder value.
'2016_WW!A2:Be',  '2017_WW!A2:Be',  '2018_WW!A2:Be',  '2019_WW!A2:Be',  '2020_WW!A2:Be', 
'2018_Aldi!A2:Be',  '2019_Aldi!A2:Be',  '2020_Aldi!A2:Be']

value_render_option = 'FORMATTED_VALUE'  

request = service.spreadsheets().values().batchGet(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, ranges=ranges, valueRenderOption=value_render_option,majorDimension='ROWS')
response = request.execute()

sheet_values = response.get('valueRanges', [])

df = json_normalize(sheet_values, sep = ",",record_path='values')
```